# Why can't I access YouTube today? PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

Tags: firefox, youtube, windows-10

I'm having no luck at all accessing Youtube today. I get this when I try to access http://youtube.com:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to www.youtube.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

I am using the current version of Firefox - it just auto-updated earlier this week - on Windows 10. I haven't had any problems with Youtube previously.

I thought it might be the specific video I was trying to watch or maybe our internet connection but my brother, who is in the same house with me and is using the same network (except that he connects with ethernet while I am on WiFi) has no trouble at all accessing YouTube and playing the exact same video I'm trying to watch.

This is not the first tab I've opened to try to access Youtube today. The first tab I opened is still there. It actually started playing the video but stopped just 4 seconds into the video and has been loading ever since, a couple of hours now.

I'm baffled by what could be happening here. We aren't using any kind of VPN or proxy server. Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm really not sure what tags to use for this problem....

Comment: Perhaps this [entry on support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1267074) might help.

Comment: https://superuser.com/ might be a better home for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a new profile with about:profiles and set it to default.
If its working, export your bookmarks from the old profile and import them again to your new profile.
in other words try to synchronize the profiles through Mozilla Account
[this link can guide you to do it](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-sync-my-computer#:%7E:text=start%20syncing%20immediately.-,Open%20Firefox%20on%20the%20computer%20or%20profile%20you%20want%20to,Now%20to%20start%20syncing%20immediately.)